# How do I log in via Stackexchange (as opposed to gmail, etc.)?

Tags: support, login

[image]

At the moment I can't access SE at school because all three of the services above are blocked  (except Stackexchange). **How do I use Stackexchange to log in?** I've tried entering 'Alyosha' and '[password]', but that doesn't seem to work. Am I, as a user, automatically registered for this login process, or do I have to activate something at the main Stackexchange site?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to create a StackExchange OpenID account and associate it with your Math.SE account first. Do the following using an Internet connection that doesn't block Gmail (or whatever login method you currently use):

1. Create a [StackExchange OpenID account](https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register). You don't have to reuse an existing password here. In fact, it's better to use a new one.
2. Go to [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/). Log in via Gmail (or your preferred method) if you aren't already.
3. Go to your user page and click 'my logins'.
4. Click 'Add login' and log in to your new StackExchange OpenID account.

Once done, you should be able to log in via StackExchange using the Internet connection at school.

Comment: Thanks (you saved me a lot of time with the thorough instructions).

Comment: @Alyosha You're welcome!